# Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format in Swift3 IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a question about formatting the Rupee currency (Indian Rupee - INR)

For example, numbers here are represented as:

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

I tried this Code:

```
var intString = 1000000
let asd = NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: NSNumber(value: Double(intString)!), number: NumberFormatter.Style.currency)
```

But this does not seem to solve the issue. Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you've tried that code? It's barely valid Swift code at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()              // Cache this, NumberFormatter creation is expensive.
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN") // Here indian locale with english language is used
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal               // Change to `.currency` if needed

let asd = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: intString)) // "10,00,000"
```

P.S. Idk why `Int` variable is called `intString` but I've kept it for consistency.